# Does Twitter/Microsoft/Yahoo OAuths need SSL?

Tags: ssl, twitter, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, yahoo-api

Hi guys this is my first time trying to handle Oauth in my project. I have read the tutorials on [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on). I have tried Google and Facebook Oauths and amazed by how simple it is. Now I am going to try Twitter / Yahoo / Microsoft just for learning purposes. **This question might land me negative points as it is a learner question.** So my question is when using Facebook Oauth you need the SSL Https URL for LocalHost machine. How about Yahoo/ Twitter/ Microsoft. Which one needs SSL.

Comment: You should always use SSL everywhere if authentication is involved.  Otherwise, attackers can simply steal your auth cookie.  (eg, Firesheep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using OAuth, you should use SSL. As a matter of fact, Twitter requires SSL on all of their endpoints as of today. If you study the protocol, you'll see that there are tokens being passed back and forth in the Authorization header. You'll want to protect those. You also want protection on the responses from the provider, which contain tokens and other info. Some applications might not require SSL (though Twitter does now), it's best practice to be secure by design, secure by default, and secure in deployment.

Answer (score 1):

No - your `localhost` machine does **not** need to be running SSL.

Indeed, even if you're not using `localhost`, there's no obligation to use SSL.  Theoretically, there's little risk if your tokens do get intercepted, because your private tokens never leave your machine.

So, the OAuth dance can be

`User -> Your Website -> SSL to OAuth provider -> Redirect to localost (non SSL)`